# How long was a trip in the Alien franchise?

Tags: alien-franchise

In *Alien* Dallas says he's been on five trips with a different science officer who was replaced on this trip with Ash.

**How long were Ripley and the Crew of the Nostromo expecting to be away from Earth?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The original trip was supposed to take "several" months in each direction, probably about 3-4. When the ship went off-course to check out the signal, it took an absolutely massive detour, placing them nearly ten months away from Earth.

Dallas wakes up thinking he's being awoken for final approach...

> *Oh well. **After several months of doing nothing but sleeping,** he had no
> right to complain if a few hours' honest sweat was now required of him
> . . .*
>
> <sub><sup>[Alien: Official Novelisation](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_(novel))</sup></sub>

The crew then find out how far off-course they've gone

> **LAMBERT:**  *It'll take us six weeks to get back on course.*
>
> **DALLAS:** *How far to Earth.*
>
> **LAMBERT:** *Ten months.*
>
> **RIPLEY:** *Christ.*
>
> <sup><sub>[Alien: Shooting Script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/alien_shooting.html)</sub></sup>

The implication being that this length of time is dramatically longer than they were expecting to be away from their home base and loved ones.